# Migrate existing MySQL database to MongoDB and use it in Django Rest Framework

Tags: mysql, mongodb, django-rest-framework, migrate

I need to use an existing MySQL Database in a new DRF Project where I want to use MongoDB as the main DB.

I've been searching which would be the better way to do so, and so far, the best I've found is to:
1- Create the DRF Project with its models, and execute manage.py makemigrations and migrate
2- Manually migrate the data from MySQL DB to the new MongoDB database using CSV

The MySQL database is pretty big, so I want to ask before doing all of that, is this correct, or is there a better way?

Comment: Usually it is a bad approach to migrate a relational database like MySQL "one-to-one" to a document oriented (or **NoSQL**) database like MongoDB. Relational databases are typically based on many tables and relations (i.e. **join** operations). NoSQL databases are not optimized for that, some NoSQL databases do not even support joins at all. Usually when you plan such migration, then you also need to review your data design.

Comment: Thanks, so maybe i should use a different approach like using PostgreSQL with HStoreField so I can have the dynamic fields

Comment: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL and I don't know your application. MongoDB might be a good choice, however migrating an application from relational RDBMS to MongoDB is typically more than a simple call of "makemigrations"